# CSS - Different sizes between Chrome and Safari

Tags: css

I am a CS freshman and I implemented a website few weeks ago but I only used Safari to verify the output and it looks much more different on Google Chrome. How can I fix this on that page? I am using `vh` for the `.showcase-container` but it looks too small with Chrome.

Safari view:

[image]

Google Chrome view:

[image]

**CSS**

```
/*ShowCase*/

body{
    background :#e6e6e6;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


#showcase{
    position: relative;
    color:white;
    padding: 2rem;
    background: #333;
}

#showcase::before{
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    background: url("../images/about/header-1.png") no-repeat center center/cover;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.4;
}


#showcase .showcase-container{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height:25vh;
}


#showcase .showcase-content{
    z-index:100;
}

.presentation .presentation-container{
    padding:5rem;
    margin:2rem;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../mobile.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="about.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../images/icon.ico">
    <title>About Us | Asia HR</title>
</head>


<body id="home">

        <nav id="navbar">
            <h1 class="logo">
                <span class="text-primary">
                  <i class="fas fa-book-open"></i>Asia      
                </span> HR
             </h1>


             <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="../services/services.html">Our Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="../search/search.php">Job Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="../article/article.php">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="../contact/contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="burger">
                    <div class="line"></div>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
        </nav>



<body>

    <header id="showcase">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="showcase-container">
                <div class="showcase-content">
                    <h1>What We Do</h1>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, tempora ullam velit quibusdam fugit odit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque enim ullam aperiam quidem? Illum nihil suscipit eveniet.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="presentation">
        <div class="presentation-container">
            <div class="presentation-text">
                <h1>Our Values</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit sit illum quod dolores sint cumque?. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, culpa.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam fugiat earum doloremque ea quaerat voluptate tempora unde, labore, ab tenetur beatae, vitae quos corrupti rem iusto distinctio iste explicabo dolorum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus quas praesentium magnam fugiat sed. Vel beatae nemo laboriosam nobis quam recusandae totam eaque quos obcaecati architecto. Quia id eius est animi saepe officia tempora! Dolor aperiam eos ipsum nesciunt officia quam tempora dolorem. Quam, temporibus.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>            
        <!--Team-->
        <div class="team-section">
                <h2>Our Team</h2>
                <span class="border border-1"></span>
                    <div class="ps">
                            <div class="p">
                                <a href="#p1"><img src="../images/home/h1.jpg"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="p">
                                <a href="#p2"><img src="../images/home/h2.jpg"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="p">
                                <a href="#p3"><img src="../images/home/h3.jpg"></a>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="section" id="p1">
                        <span class="name">Sophia Letana</span>
                        <span class="border border-1"></span>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat tenetur assumenda omnis, rem, quas quae odit, voluptatem dolorum quod corrupti sint doloribus aspernatur? Quasi, dolore?</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="section" id="p2">
                        <span class="name">Francois Le Chene</span>
                        <span class="border border-1"></span>
                        <p>gh ghgh ghg sit, amet consectetur ghgh elit. Placeat tenetur assumenda omnis, rem, quas quae odit, voluptatem dolorum quod corrupti sint doloribus aspernatur? Quasi, dolore?</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="section" id="p3">
                        <span class="name">Steve Mansoa</span>
                        <span class="border border-1"></span>
                        <p>Lghgh ipsum gh sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat tenetur assumenda omnis, rem, quas quae odit, voluptatem dolorum quod corrupti sint doloribus aspernatur? Quasi, dolore?</p>
                    </div>      
            </div>
</body>

        <!-- Footer -->

        <div class="footer">
                <div class="footer-sections">
                    <div class="adress-footer">
                        <h4>Contact</h4>
                        <p>102, Pyidaungsu Yeithka Road,
                                 Yangon, Myanmar</p>
                        <p>+33 6 24 15 14 02</p>
                        <p>contact@hrasia.com</p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="menu-footer">
                            <h4>Operating Hours</h4>
                            <p>Monday - Friday :  8 a.m - 5 p.m</p>
                            <p>Saturday :  9 a.m - 1 p.m</p>
                            <p>Sunday :  closed</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h4>Blog</h4>
                        <p>Read our latest posts</p>
                        <p>How to write a resume ?</p> 
                        <p>The interview process</p>                       
                        </div>

                </div>
                <div class="footer-bottom">
                        <p>&copy; hrasia.com | Designed by Pierre-Alexandre Mousset</p>
                </div>

        </div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCGtFf0pMBZa-fBYFkG-pANG4UdvD1Q_es&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>

<script src="../main.js"></script>
<script src="contact.js"></script>

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the height for showcase container. Instead use paddings for the div instead. This will let it grow as required.

```
#showcase .showcase-container{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

or you can also set min-height,if you want to have a certain height of the showcase.

```
#showcase .showcase-container{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height:25vh;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px; 
}
```

Giving the height will make that stay that way and not expand although the child elements ask for it.